# Please help correct this bug: reading integers line by line from a file using fscanf in c

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I tried using this code:

```
int index = 0; 
int value;
int IntegerArray[MAXARRAYSIZE];
while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &value) == 1){ 
    IntegerArray[index++] = value; 
}
```

but I received this error:

> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
>   Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00000038
>   0x98a7c1ea in __svfscanf_l ()

`fp` is of type `FILE` and I believe I have used all necessary library inclusions. Please help.

Comment: The first thing you do when getting a crash, is to run your program in a debugger. Not only will it help you pinpoint the location of the crash, it will also let you examine variables to see what might have caused the crash.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if `index` is less than `MAXARRAYSIZE` or not. Otherwise, you will be going out of bounds and invoke undefined behavior (typically invalid memory access).

Change

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &value) == 1)
```

to

```
while((1 == fscanf(fp, "%d", &value)) && (index < MAXARRAYSIZE))
```

You cannot store integers than you have defined the array size.

Comment: The coding style [integer literal] == [expression] has been obsolete since Borland Turbo C was released 1990. It had a warning against "possible incorrect assignment", and every compiler ever made since then has that warning. I wouldn't encourage people to adopt >20 years old coding style tricks.

Comment: @Lundin: People make the same mistakes time and again. Newbies tend to mix up `==` and `=` within a condition. This helps them spot the error. It is only with experience that you learn to respect the compiler's warnings.

Comment: If they ignore compiler warnings, then they deserve the bugs.

Answer (score 1):

you might be exceeding your maxrraysize, as such you are trying to access memory that doesn't belong to your program, so it might be wise to check for that, also please initialize your array just to be safe, since it typically holds what ever previous values where on that location.

```
int index = 0; 
int value;
int IntegerArray[MAXARRAYSIZE] = {0};

while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &value) == 1){ 
    if (index >= MAXARRAYSIZE)
    {
         printf("reached max array size!\n");
         break ;
    }
IntegerArray[index++] = value; 
}
```